# Show the number of answers in the duplicate banner message

Tags: feature-request, design, duplicate-questions

This is currently how the number of answers a duplicate question has is shown:

[image: pic1]

I think this is better:

[image: pic2]

Just because it would be simpler and looks nicer.

Comment: What will you do when there are two duplicates? "This question already has 3 answers here and 4 answers there"? Not very elegant. Example: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75010/create-a-stack-overflowish-private-instance-for-student-projects.

Comment: @ShadowWizard Well, just use this format when there is only one duplicate.

Comment: @ShadowWizard In your example I think "This question already has 7 answers here" followed by the two linked duplicates would work.